# Problema em linguagem C, questão com números primos

Tags: c, algoritmo, array

Estou resolvendo exercícios, em linguagem C, sobre vetores. O exercício é o seguinte:
Faça um algoritmo que utilize um menu com as seguintes opções: ordenar um vetor de 5 posições crescente, ordenar um vetor de 5 posições decrescente e armazenar em um vetor 2, os números primos. 
O problema ocorre quando é selecionada a terceira opção do menu, sendo ela a de armazenar os números primos em um segundo vetor. 
Queria que dessem uma olhada no meu 'case 3' do switch e me apontem o(s) erro(s).
Agradeço desde já.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");
int op, vetor[5], i, x, y, w=0, aux, cont=0, primos[5]; 

    do{

        printf("\n      Menu    \n");
        printf("0. Sair. \n");
        printf("1. Ordenar de forma crescente. \n");
        printf("2. Ordenar de forma decrescente. \n");
        printf("3. Armazenar os números primos. \n");

        printf("Digite a opção desejada: ");
        scanf("%d", &op);

        if(op==0){

            break;

        }

        system("cls");

        switch(op){

            case 1: printf("Você escolheu ordenar de forma crescente. \n");

                    for(i=0; i<5; i++){

                        printf("Digite o elemento [%d]: ", i);
                        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);

                    }

                    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
                        for(x=0; x<=5; x++){

                            if(vetor[i]<vetor[x]){

                                aux = vetor[i];
                                vetor[i] = vetor[x]; 
                                vetor[x] = aux;

                            }                               
                        }                           
                    }

                    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
                        printf("\nv[%d] = %d\n", i, vetor[i]); 
                    }

                    break;

            case 2: printf("Você escolheu ordenar de forma decrescente. \n");

                    for(i=0; i<5; i++){

                        printf("Digite o elemento [%d]: ", i);
                        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);

                    }

                    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
                        for(x=0; x<=4; x++){

                            if(vetor[x]<vetor[i]){

                                aux = vetor[x];
                                vetor[x] = vetor[i]; 
                                vetor[i] = aux;

                            }                               
                        }                           
                    }

                    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
                        printf("\nv[%d] = %d\n", i, vetor[i]); 
                    }

                    break;

            case 3: printf("Você escolheu armazenar os números primos. \n");

                    for(i=0; i<5; i++){

                        printf("Digite o elemento [%d]: ", i);
                        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);

                    }

                    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
                        for(y=1; y<=vetor[i]; i++){

                            if(vetor[i]%y==0){
                                cont++;
                            }
                            w=0;
                            if(cont==2){

                                primos[w] = vetor[i];
                                w++; 

                            }


                        }

                        for(i=0; i<5; i++){

                            printf("primo[%d] = %d\n", i, primos[i]);

                        }

                    break;



                    }

        }

        }while(op!=0);  

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mas qual é o problema?

Answer (score 4):

Bem, primeiramente eu recomendo você a aprender a identar o seu código de forma adequada. Outro ponto é que você exagera no uso de linhas em branco.

Mas quanto aos erros, o primeiro está no `case 1`:

```
for(x=0; x<=5; x++){
```

Ali, o `<=5` deveria ser `< 5` ou então `<= 4`.

Agora, vamos dar uma olhada no seu `case 3`. Já dei uma arrumada no excesso de linhas em branco e arrumei a identação para entendermos melhor:

```
printf("Você escolheu armazenar os números primos. \n");

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("Digite o elemento [%d]: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (y = 1; y <= vetor[i]; i++) {
        if (vetor[i] % y == 0) {
            cont++;
        }
        w = 0;
        if (cont == 2) {
            primos[w] = vetor[i];
            w++; 
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("primo[%d] = %d\n", i, primos[i]);
    }
    break;
}
```

E olha só o que a identação correta nos revelou: Você tem um laço iterando no `i` dentro de um outro laço iterando também no `i`. Além disso, o fato de o `break` estar dentro do `for` quando ele deveria estar interrompendo o `switch` ao invés do `for` mostra que há algo muito errado nisso. A lição aqui aprendida é a evitar linhas em branco em excesso e a identar corretamente, pois bastou esses dois passos simples para que esse problema se tornasse óbvio.

Ok, vamos corrigir isso. O primeiro laço que contém os `scanf`s está correto. Já o segundo laço está fechando muito tardiamente, pois ele deveria conter apenas o laço interno que itera no `y` e nada mais. Assim sendo, o seu código por enquanto fica assim:

```
printf("Você escolheu armazenar os números primos. \n");

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("Digite o elemento [%d]: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (y = 1; y <= vetor[i]; i++) {
        if (vetor[i] % y == 0) {
            cont++;
        }
        w = 0;
        if (cont == 2) {
            primos[w] = vetor[i];
            w++; 
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("primo[%d] = %d\n", i, primos[i]);
}
break;
```

Um outro problema está no `w`. A finalidade do `w` é marcar quantos primos você achou. Mas o laço interno (o do `y`) verifica cada possibilidade de divisão e para cada uma ele volta o `w` para o zero de novo, o que faz com que ele sempre fique preso em zero no final. Na verdade, o `w = 0;` deveria estar antes deste laço.

Aliás, olhando para o laço interno, você inicializa `y = 0`, verifica a condição de parada com `y <= vetor[i]`, mas incrementa com `i++` ao invés de `y++`. Obviamente, o correto é incrementar com `y++`.

Olhando para o `if`, a finalidade dele é registrar que um primo foi encontrado apenas se exatamente dois divisores tiverem sido encontrados no laço do `y`. Entretanto, isso significa que ele deveria estar depois do laço do `y`, e não dentro.

O último `for` percorre o array com os primos encontrados. Como saber quantos primos foram encontrados? Bem, esse é o propósito do `w`. Isso significa que o último `for` deveria iterar por `w` elementos do array, e não por 5.

E por fim, a variável `cont` deveria ter o seu valor reinicializado para zero em cada iteração do laço intermediário que descobre se o número é primo. Afinal, se este valor não for resetado, ele vai acumulando de um número para outro e entre diferentes execuções do `case 3` e isso não tem sentido. Logo, ele tem que ser setado em zero no começo do laço intermediário.

Assim sendo, eis como o seu código corrigido fica:

```
printf("Você escolheu armazenar os números primos. \n");

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("Digite o elemento [%d]: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
}

w = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cont = 0;
    for (y = 1; y <= vetor[i]; y++) {
        if (vetor[i] % y == 0) {
            cont++;
        }
    }
    if (cont == 2) {
        primos[w] = vetor[i];
        w++; 
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    printf("primo[%d] = %d\n", i, primos[i]);
}
break;
```

Comment: agradeço seus conselhos em relação a identação e o uso das linhas, não tinha consciência sobre identação e como sou iniciante, irei logo aprender sobre. As linhas eu utilizo por questão de organização pessoal, não consigo prestar atenção quando o código está muito "grudado", mas irei melhorar nesse aspecto.

Comment: em relação ao código em si, fiz as devidas modificações e continua dando erro. Anteriormente, o resultado caia em lixo, e agora não exibe absolutamente nada.

Comment: @MilenaTeixeira Resposta editada e corrigida. É que no `for` do `y` você estava usando `i++` ao invés de `y++` e este erro havia me passado despercebido.